# Adding jars to java webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

I am getting this error when I try to run my java webapp on a Tomcat server. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity`. I have included the appropriate jars, but according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9663942/1546713), I am supposed to import the external jars into `WEB-INF/lib`. However, when I add external jars, by right-clicking on the project and choosing "buildpath -> configure build path..." it adds them to `project_name/Java Resources/Libraries`. How do I add these jars to the correct place in the project so they will be found?

Comment: Copy-past them into WEB-INF/lib folder. That should be enought

Comment: Copy the required jar's to `WEB-INF/lib` and add these jars to build path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add libraries in eclipse, it adds them in build path so that your project gets compiled. But its not enough to run it on tomcat. for tomcat to be able to pick referenced libraries these must be kept in web-inf\lib folder. You can just copy-paste them into folder structure. Then just restart the server, it must be able to find those libraries.