# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException while using the jsonparser()

Tags: java, httpclient, agents-jade

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
    at situasses.Situassess.<init>(Situassess.java:24)
    at myproject.RecomAgent.setup(RecomAgent.java:33)
    at jade.core.Agent$ActiveLifeCycle.init(Agent.java:1522)
    at jade.core.Agent.run(Agent.java:1468)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 5 more
```

ERROR: Agent user61 died without being properly terminated !!!
State was 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `HTTPClient.jar` to your classpath. And also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663927/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-client-httpclient) for details.

Comment: i have already added HTTPclient.4.3.1.jar..but it is not working...i am using java 1.7.0_45is there any compatibility issue..because when i run it on another system its executing succesfully but on the server having same java its giving the above mentioned error at jsonparser.