# Could not initialize class using OpenBlueDragon CFML

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfml, openbd

I am working with the OpenBD ColdFusion engine and I am using Java code from SendGrid in my project. I am getting the following error:

```
 Could not initialize class 
     org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory 
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

This code is running on an Adobe ColdFusion server fine. I have added all of the required jar files in the lib folder.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with OpenBD but it looks like the jar/class files are not loaded. Are you sure it is picking up the files from the directory?

Comment: *Update:* Could also be caused by [multiple versions of a lib in the class path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663927/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-client-httpclient). Which "required jars" did you load? Does OpenBD core already contain any of those libs?

Comment: Thankyou. I have solved the  problem.

Comment: @Rajesh - please post your solution as an answer to your own question here. It is okay to do that and will likely help someone else down the road. Glad you figured it out.